# Proof on orthogonal projectors

Tags: matrices, projection-matrices

I was reading an alternative orthogonal projector proof.

Let $P$ be an orthogonal projector. Why does $P = P^T P$ imply $P^T = P$ and $P^2 = P$?

Answer (score 3):

Because $P^T=(P^TP)^T=P^TP=P$ and thus $P^2=PP=P^TP=P$